# Using jQuery in certain screen sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need a mobile navigation to stick after the user has scrolled a certain amount. When a user has scrolled 205px on desktop resolution the navigation will stick no problem.

How do I change this to 64px after the screen size has gone below 767px? and how do I cancel the desktop jQuery from taking effect on a mobile?

Current desktop javascript:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 205) {
        $('.sidemenu').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('.sidemenu').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

Current mobile javascript:

```
function checkPosition() {
    if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches) {
          $(window).scroll(function(){
              if ($(this).scrollTop() > 64) {
                  $('.sidemenu').addClass('fixed');
              } else {
                  $('.sidemenu').removeClass('fixed');
              }
          })
     }
};
```

Suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a class `mobile` to your `body` for example when the matchmedia matches.

```
$(document.body).toggleClass('mobile', window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches);
```

Once you have that, the `checkPosition` simply has to get the proper scrollTop value.

```
function checkPosition() {
    var scrollY = $(document.body).hasClass('mobile') ? 64 : 205;

    $('.sidemenu').toggleClass('fixed', $(window).scrollTop() > scrollY);
};
```

Or simply add the matchMedia test instead of the hasClass test.

Additionally, I expect the height of the "fixed container" to be dynamic.
Maybe something like:

```
var scrollY = $('header').height(); // just an idea ofcourse to get 64 or 205.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check screens size in resize wvent like this

```
   var width;
   $(window).resize(function () {
        width = $("html").width();
    });
```

than in scroll event (or in other place) you can check:

```
     if (width  <= 767) {
        // do some for small screen
     }
     else if (width > 767 && width < 1200) {
      // do some for medium screen
     }
     //if..
```